# Most fluid way to perform jquery animation for float tiles?

Tags: jquery, animation, chat, slidetoggle, fluid

I am making a web chat using Jquery and am currently working on making the menu. It works just fine but i can't seem to get the animation right. when the script fires, it looks as if the previous elements do not perform their animation. any ideas?

```
$('div.menutile').click(function(){
    if ($(this).css('height') == '105px'){
        $('#Menu').css('overflow-y','hide');
        $(this).prevAll().toggle("slide", {direction: "down"},300);
        $(this).delay(300).animate(300).css('height','95.6%');
        $(this).delay(300).nextAll().toggle("slide", {direction: "up"},300);
        $(this).delay(300).animate(300).css('width','345px');
        $('#Menu').css('overflow-y','scroll');
    }else {
        $('#Menu').css('overflow-y','hide');
        $(this).prevAll().toggle("slide", {direction: "up"},300);
        $(this).delay(300).animate(300).css('height','105px');
        $(this).delay(300).nextAll().toggle("slide", {direction: "up"},300);
        $(this).delay(300).animate(300).css('width','155px');
        $('#Menu').css('overflow-y','scroll');
    };
});
```

this is what it looks like before and after if it helps at all

**Before:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLnw3.png
**After:**
http://i.imgur.com/66Hc6sN.png

Comment: can you provide an example in jsfiddle please?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NotDragon/m0dhhbyv/

Comment: @RozzA http://jsfiddle.net/NotDragon/m0dhhbyv/